# Cmake inlclude a custom library in another custom library

Tags: c++, cmake

I am trying to include one custom library (LibraryTwo) to another custom library (LibraryOne) using cmake but get the error that the included library cannot be found.
Original error when hovering mouse over the include statement:

> Basierend auf den von der configurationProvider-Einstellung bereitgestellten Informationen wurden #include-Fehler festgestellt. Wellenlinien sind für diese Übersetzungseinheit deaktiviert (C:\Users\...\myLibraries\LibraryOne\src\thisFile.cpp).C/C++(1696)
> Die Datei "Quelle" kann nicht geöffnet werden: "myLibraries/LibraryTwo/myFile2.h".C/C++(1696)

Translation

> Based on the information provided by the configurationProvider setting, #include error was detected. Wavelines are disabled for this translation unit (C:\Users\...\myLibraries\LibraryOne\src\thisFile.cpp).C/C++(1696)
> The Source file cannot be opened: "myLibraries/LibraryTwo/myFile2.h".C/C++(1696)

I use the following include statement in a cpp file in LibraryOne-> src

```
#include "LibraryTwo/myFile2.h"
```

The **project structure** in **visual studio code** is like this:

```
MyProject

.vscode
MyProject-> mainFile.cpp
MyProject-> src (with cpp file and main method)
MyProject-> include (with corresponding .h files)

MyProject-> MyLiraries
MyProject-> MyLiraries-> CmakeLists.txt

MyProject-> MyLiraries-> LibraryOne
MyProject-> MyLiraries-> LibraryOne-> src (with cpp files)
MyProject-> MyLiraries-> LibraryOne-> include (with corresponding .h files)
MyProject-> MyLiraries-> LibraryOne-> CmakeLists.txt

MyProject-> MyLiraries-> LibraryTwo
MyProject-> MyLiraries-> LibraryTwo-> src (with cpp files)
MyProject-> MyLiraries-> LibraryTwo-> include (with corresponding .h files)
MyProject-> MyLiraries-> LibraryOne-> CmakeLists.txt
```

I use the following code for the CmakeLists.txt files in folders **LibraryTwo** and **LibraryOne**

```
project(MyProject)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
add_compile_options("-Wall" "-Wextra")

find_package(myLibraries)
include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR})

add_library(LibraryOne"")
add_library(myLibs::LibraryOne ALIAS LibraryOne)
[...]
include(GNUInstallDirs)
install( 
  TARGET LibraryOne
  EXPORT myLibrariesTargets
  ARCHIVE DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}
  )
```

The cmake in the folder MyProject -> My Libraries with the library installation is as following

```
project(MyProject)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
add_compile_options("-Wall" "-Wextra")
include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR})

install(
  EXPORT myLibrariesTargets
  DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}/cmake/myLibraries
  NAMESPACE myLibraries::
  FILE myLibrariesTargets.cmake 
  )

include(CMakePackageConfigHelpers)
configure_package_config_file( 
  "Config.cmake.in" 
  "myLibrariesConfig.cmake"
  INSTALL_DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}/cmake/myLibraries
  PATH_VARS
    CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR
  )

write_basic_package_version_file(
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/myLibrariesConfigVersion.cmake
  VERSION 1.0.0
  COMPATIBILITY SameMajorVersion
  )

### Install Config and ConfigVersion files
install(
  FILES "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/myLibrariesConfig.cmake"
        "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/myLibrariesConfigVersion.cmake"
  DESTINATION "${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}/cmake/myLibraries"
  )
```

Uppermost Cmake in MyProject

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.9)
project(myProject)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
add_compile_options("-Wall" "-Wextra")
include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR})


include_directories(src include)

find_package(myLibraries)

add_executable(myMain mainFile.cpp)
```

The Config.cmake.in in folder MyProject

```
@PACKAGE_INIT@
include( "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/MyLibsTargets.cmake" )
```

How can I properly define my libraries and include them to each other or to my main files in MyProject-> src ?

PS: I am rather new to cpp and cmake and probably missing some standard procedure to do this. As such I  would be very happy to receive some help as my google research (from with the cmake layouts origin) has not helped at all.
PS2: As english is not my first language some terminology might be completely wrong. I apologise in advance.

Comment: Description "get the error that the included library cannot be found." is quite vague. Could you provide the **exact error message** you got?

Comment: Don't use `include_directories`. Use `target_include_directories` instead (using the approach presented in the second code snippet there: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_include_directories.html), use `install(DIRECTORY)` to copy the include dir and make sure the headers are actually placed in a subdirectory of `include` matching the lib name (the relative path `LibraryTwo/myFile2.h` must the correct path to the header file from at least one of the include dirs).

Comment: @Tsyvarev I only have the errormessage in german but I hope the translation is enough.

Comment: The path in the error message `The Source file cannot be opened: "myLibraries/LibraryTwo/myFile2.h"` clearly conflicts with the one you show us `#include "LibraryTwo/myFile2.h"`. It seems you include your libraries projects via `add_subdirectory` call, but this call is not shown neither in top-level `CMakeLists.txt` nor in `CMakeLists.txt` under `MyLiraries`. Because you cannot even to build the library, then `install` directives (which install these libraries) are unrelated to your problem. The same is about `find_package(myLibraries)`, `CMakePackageConfigHelpers` and `Config.cmake.in`.

Comment: If library `LibraryOne` **uses** `LibraryTwo` (e.g. by including its header file), then the libraries should be **linked** (with `target_link_libraries`). That linkage will transfers include directories, added for `LibraryTwo` via `target_include_directories`, to `LibraryOne` library.